# How do I print value of json object using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm techy102 and I am making a project where you configure a JSON file and python prints those values in the shell, but when I select an object it gives me this:

```
{'print1': 'hello, world!'}
```

I know this is what you expect from printing a JSON string but I wanted the output to be this:

```
hello, world!
```

but I don't know how to do that. if any of you know, please tell me, thanks!

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can access a dictionaries value by it's key. Like you open a door with a key.

```
dictEx = {'print1': 'hello, world!'}
print(dictEx['print1'])
```

And say you don't have the key to "open the door"/"access the value".
A dictionary can return you a list of keys with `dictEx.keys()`.
Below is an example of how you can use that.

```
dictEx = {'print1': 'hello, world!'}
for key in dictEx.keys():
    print(dictEx[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the json file into a dictionary and then get the value of the corresponding key.

In your case:

```
yourDict = json.load(loaded_json_file)
print(yourDict['print1'])
```